# Eigen fails to compile with "Reference to EBX in function requiring stack alignment" when compiling with AVX2

Tags: c++, eigen

We are porting code from SSE (-msse4.2) to AVX2 (-march=core-avx2) and using `__m256` intrinsics over `__m128` intrinsics.

When Eigen gets compiled like this:

```
/opt/intel/composer_xe_2015.2.164/bin/intel64/icpc -std=c++11 \
    -w2 -Werror -march=core-avx2  -O3 -g  ...
```

This is the obscure error message that is not documented:

```
/eigen/eigen-3.2.5/Eigen/src/Core/products/SelfadjointProduct.h(87): \
  (col. 3) error #13212: Reference to EBX in function requiring stack alignment
```

Here is our code that refers to `selfadjoint`:

```
   const Eigen::Matrix2f ncov = refLinv * covSlice * refLinv.transpose();
   Eigen::Vector2f ev = ncov.selfadjointView<Eigen::Lower>().eigenvalues();
```

For reference, here is the Eigen source code (makes my eyes bleed to read the template arguments):

```
template<typename MatrixType, typename OtherType, int UpLo>
struct selfadjoint_product_selector<MatrixType,OtherType,UpLo,false>
{
  static void run(MatrixType& mat, const OtherType& other, const typename MatrixType::Scalar& alpha)
  {
    typedef typename MatrixType::Scalar Scalar;
    typedef typename MatrixType::Index Index;
    typedef internal::blas_traits<OtherType> OtherBlasTraits;
    typedef typename OtherBlasTraits::DirectLinearAccessType ActualOtherType;
    typedef typename internal::remove_all<ActualOtherType>::type _ActualOtherType;
    typename internal::add_const_on_value_type<ActualOtherType>::type actualOther = OtherBlasTraits::extract(other.derived());

    Scalar actualAlpha = alpha * OtherBlasTraits::extractScalarFactor(other.derived());

    enum { IsRowMajor = (internal::traits<MatrixType>::Flags&RowMajorBit) ? 1 : 0 };

    internal::general_matrix_matrix_triangular_product<Index,
      Scalar, _ActualOtherType::Flags&RowMajorBit ? RowMajor : ColMajor,   OtherBlasTraits::NeedToConjugate  && NumTraits<Scalar>::IsComplex,
      Scalar, _ActualOtherType::Flags&RowMajorBit ? ColMajor : RowMajor, (!OtherBlasTraits::NeedToConjugate) && NumTraits<Scalar>::IsComplex,
      MatrixType::Flags&RowMajorBit ? RowMajor : ColMajor, UpLo>
      ::run(mat.cols(), actualOther.cols(),
            &actualOther.coeffRef(0,0), actualOther.outerStride(), &actualOther.coeffRef(0,0), actualOther.outerStride(),
            mat.data(), mat.outerStride(), actualAlpha);
  }
};
```

This compiles fine with -msse4.2.

Any hints what EBX has to do with AVX2?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce your problem with icpc 16.0.3, Eigen 3.2.9 and the following code. You may want to upgrade your compiler and Eigen library, or create a MCVE code that reproduces your problem.

```
#include <Eigen/Eigen>

int main() {
  Eigen::Matrix2f tmp;
  tmp << 2, 1, 1, 2;
  const Eigen::Matrix2f ncov = tmp;
  Eigen::Vector2f ev = ncov.selfadjointView<Eigen::Lower>().eigenvalues();
  return 0;
}
```